# How to get the likes and dislikes of Feed Comment

Tags: visualforce, chatter

I would like to know how to get the disLikes of the FeedComment.

This one helped me to resolved getting of "likes" but not dislikes.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BPzIIAW

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not checking the right item, the object that normally has downvotes is the [Reply](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_reply.htm) object, whic can be found in the Soap Api Developer docs.

> DownVotes - The total number of down votes for a reply.